# How to Implement Screen Freeze in Godot

Tags: 2d, godot

Many 2D games have an intentional screen freeze (say, 75 milliseconds) when the player takes or deals damage. During this freeze, all physics and animation processing stops.

**How can one implement a screen freeze in Godot?**

If you want to suggest how to do this in Unity or another engine, that's fine too. It might help me to figure out how to do it in Godot.

---

My only idea is to have a boolean called `is_screen_freeze` along with some variables `freeze_start_time` and `freeze_duration`. In all my nodes' `_process()` and `_physics_process()`methods, I can just pass if `is_screen_freeze` is true. This seems like a rather inelegant way of going about a screen freeze, and I'm not even sure it would work since animations would probably keep playing. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can stop physics processing by pausing the scene tree: http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/misc/pausing_games.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As flesk already stated, Godot has a very good pause function. You can just call

```
get_tree().paused = true
```

However,  this will basically stop all physics, process and input functions making your game completely non-responsible.

Since your game obviously should recover after a short time, I would just create a new node that doesn't inherit the pause property from its parent (this can be set in the editor) but is set to process mode. You could then create a signal that is emitted by this node after a given amount of time. For example with the timer node:

```
freeze_timer = Timer.new()
freeze_timer.connect("timeout", self, "on_freeze_timeout")
freeze_timer.set_wait_time(0.075) # time in seconds
add_child(freeze_timer)
timer.start()
```

Finally you create an `on_freeze_timeout` function to catch the signal.

```
func on_freeze_timeout():
    get_tree().paused = false
```

Alternatively, you could also create a dedicated Timer node and just call it or use the process() function to count up to the time you want. However, with the latter your timing might be a bit off, depending on the time that passed between two function calls.

Comment: You can just use `yield(get_tree().create_timer(0.075), 'timeout')` between `get_tree().paused = true` and `get_tree().paused = false`. This is way more readable and shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with Godot but I have done this in Unity.

Taking a quick look at the documentation, I'd say you can pause the game using `OS.set_time_scale(0.0)` and get the current ms ticks (milliseconds since start of the engine) with `OS.get_ticks_msec()`

This would freeze the simulation, as `delta` would be 0 each frame. You then can wait the amount of time you want by comparing your stored ms ticks with the current `OS.get_ticks_msec()`, and once the 75 milliseconds has passed, you can set `OS.set_time_scale(1.0)` to keep the execution.